# Последний элемент с hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть пять div-ов , и по умолчанию у них есть какой то hover,нужно сделать так чтобы у последнего с которого мы отвели мышку,оставался hover;
скрипт что то типа

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
      function(){
        $(".leftBlock").hover(function(){
          $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("image_src"))},
          function(){$("#image").attr("src","default_image_url");}
      });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image1.jpg">
Left Block 1
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image2.jpg">
Left Block 2
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image3.jpg">
Left Block 3
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image4.jpg">
Left Block 4
</div>
<div class="leftBlock" image_src="image5.jpg">
Left Block 5
</div>

 <div id="image_div" ><img id="image" src="default.jpg"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Буду признателен за помощь с jQuery знаком но с ним я на Вы )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование .hover() - в вашем случае не оправдано. Его лучше использовать, когда необходимо обратное действи при отведении курсора от элемента. Используйте mouseenter() или mouseover().
[Примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/yRX3t/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="some_list">
    <a href="">Point 1</a>
    <a href="">Point 2</a>
    <a href="">Point 3</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var listPoint = $("#some_list a");
listPoint.mouseenter(function(){
    listPoint.css({
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        color: '#000'
    })
    $(this).css({
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#060'
    });
});
```

В вашем случае - достаточно:

```
$(".leftBlock").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("image_src"));
});
```

До тех пор, пока не будет наведен курсор на следующий элемент *#leftBlock*, картинка останется не изменной.

Comment: в моем случае так: слева пять блоков, а справа блок с картинками и при наведении на соответствующий блок выводится соответствующая картинка и когда уводишь мышь с последнего(не пятого а вообще последний на котором была мышь) там должен остаться стиль(CSS прописанный ему).

Comment: Тогда [вот таким макаром](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/yRX3t/1/)

Comment: Решил вашу проблему! Незабудте принять мой ответ :)

Comment: Пробуйте так:

    $(".leftBlock").hover(
        function(){
            $(".leftBlock").css('background-image','none');
            $(this).css('background','url("/img/arrow4.png") 0 0 no-repeat'); // или полный путь к картинке http://test.atameken-kz.com/img/arrow4.png
            $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("image_src"))
        },
        function(){
            $("#image").attr("src")
        }
    );

P.S. @gold, примите уже в конце концов ответ у @Rules, ему очень надо )))

Comment: У вас есть скайп ,можете помочь ? Я так чувствую не пойму.

Comment: У вас на странице кусок кода:

   $(".leftBlock").hover(function(){
          $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("image_src"))},
          function(){$("#image").attr("src")});

Замените его на то, что я вам показал

Answer (score 1):

Долго думал и решил вашу проблему!:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>brg</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divobj" style="left: 0px;" id="1">A</div>
<div class="divobj" style="left: 30px;" id="2">B</div>
<div class="divobj" style="left: 60px;" id="3">C</div>
<style>
.divobj{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 top: 0px;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var lastSelectedId=0;
var divObjs=document.getElementsByClassName("divobj");
  for(var i=0;i<divObjs.length;i++){
    divObj=divObjs[i];
    divObj.onmouseover=function(evt){
     divObj=window.event?event.srcElement:evt.target;
     if(divObj.id!=lastSelectedId){
      lastSelectedId=divObj.id;
      divObj.style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";
      for(var i=0;i<divObjs.length;i++){
        if(divObjs[i].id!=lastSelectedId){
           divObjs[i].style.backgroundColor="";
        }
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPD***
Решение без id (может не работать в совсем древних браузерах):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>brg</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divobj" style="left: 0px;">A</div>
<div class="divobj" style="left: 30px;">B</div>
<div class="divobj" style="left: 60px;">C</div>
<style>
.divobj{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 top: 0px;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var lastSelectedObj=0;
var divObjs=document.getElementsByClassName("divobj");
  for(var i=0;i<divObjs.length;i++){
    divObj=divObjs[i];
    divObj.onmouseover=function(evt){
     divObj=window.event?event.srcElement:evt.target;
     if(divObj!=lastSelectedObj){
      lastSelectedObj=divObj;
      divObj.style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";
      for(var i=0;i<divObjs.length;i++){
        if(divObjs[i]!=lastSelectedObj){
           divObjs[i].style.backgroundColor="";
        }
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Только надо каждому элементу присвоить свой id чтоб всё работало...

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием принял что ты сделал,но у меня есть еще блок с картинками,и там не правильно будет каждому id присваивать.

Comment: Хм надо подумать ещё может придумается чтото без id... Спасибо @gold что придумываешь мне задачки по JS:)

Comment: Да не за что,дело случая )

Comment: Вот посмотрите UPD придумал решение без использования ID